# P-adic Numbers and Eternal Inflation

Tags: measure-theory, physics, mathematical-physics

In October(??) 2011, Leonard Susskind gave a talk and with few other people wrote a paper about P-adic numbers and measure problems(??) in cosmology. Has there been any recent talks, papers, developments in same topic?

P.S. I do not know which tags are appropriate. I appreciate any help with correcting tags. I also posted this in PhysicsSE but it seems to be less active than MathSE.

**Added** : To see the original paper see [Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0496v4.pdf).

Comment: Could you say something about the relation? The paper by Susskind?

Comment: It's Titled [Eternal Symmetree](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0496).

Comment: citation with link to the original preprint?

Comment: And I am not an expert and was interested in P-adic numbers and discovered this. I just wish to explore it more.

Comment: If you're interested in p-adic numbers and you have a basic undergraduate level in mathematics (basic calculus, linear algebra, abstrac algebra and topology), I wholeheartedly recommend the book "p-adic Numbers" , by Fernando Q. Gouvea. It's really nice and gentle.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48141/2451

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you wanted, but this is an article about the use of p-adic numbers in physics (including cosmology):

http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/padicreview.pdf